# Как изменить свойства окна с помощью Angular 2?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Может кто подскажет как можно на Angular 2 изменять свойства окна браузера - разрешение, ориентация. Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать объект window - только как к нему добраться с помощью Typescript?

Comment: declare var window:any;

Answer (score 1):

Да так же как и в js. Есть объект window и он здесь даже будет с автодополнением, так как строгая типизация.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/141939)

Comment: @Yuri, почему это не ответ? Отвечающий говорит, что объект `window` является глобальным, как в JavaScript.

Comment: @Arhad, этот ответ тянет на комментарий. К ответу нужно приложить код или более подробно рассказать о решении проблемы

Comment: я новичек, и не могу коментировать вопрос.

Comment: Теперь можете (пока с удалением этого ответа не откатилась репутация за плюсы).

Comment: declare var window:any;

Answer (score 0):

Самый кашерный вариант - советуют создать сервис и инжектить его в нужные компоненты.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function _window() : any {
   return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRef {
   get nativeWindow() : any {
      return _window();
   }
}
```